# Draw dotted line under the circle in google map

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am working on an Android application that uses Google Maps and draws circle on the map so i have created the circle on the map but now i need to draw a dotted line in the circle to show the radius of that circle.
Is there a way do draw a dotted line in the circle[image]

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 3):

use

```
       setStrokePattern(List<PatternItem> pattern)
```

on the line with its starting point being the center of circle and ending point being the (centerLatitude+radius,centerLongitude).

Here the List  can be any type of pattern, e,g, in your case it can be like:

```
    setStrokePattern(Arrays.asList(new Dash(60), new Gap(60)))
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Pattern Item](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PatternItem) and [setStrokePattern](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle#setStrokePattern(java.util.List%3Ccom.google.android.gms.maps.model.PatternItem%3E)) and [Circle](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle)

Comment: I want to change marker position in the map using a touch listener. I do not want to use drag listener because it requires a long click

Comment: On click event get the x and y co ordinate and reposition your circle.